# How to insert values with custom column name (updated_at) in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have table `customtables` with following columns

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
My-Id(int-primarykey-autoincrement) | My-column-Name(string) | My-Created-By(int) |
My-Created-Time(timestamp) | MY-Updated-By(int) | My-updated-Time(timestamp)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I will try to insert data with this code

```
$mymodelclass = new mymodelclass;
$mymodelclass->My-column-Name = Input::get('column-name');
--------------------------
--------------------------
$mymodelclass->My-Created-By =  Auth::user()->Login_Id;
$mymodelclass->My-Created-Time = DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');
$mymodelclass->save();
```

and `mymodelclass` is this

```
class Asset extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = array('My-column-Name,My-Created-By,...,My-Created-Time,
                                                 MY-Updated-By,My-updated-Time');
    protected $primaryKey = "My-Id";
    protected $table = 'customtables';
}
```

But I got this error

```
 Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' 
 (SQL: insert into `customtables` 
 (`My-column-Name`,..., `My-Created-Time`,`updated_at`, `created_at`) 
 values 
 (Qwerty,..., CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 2014-02-08 14:53:53, 2014-02-08 14:53:53))
```

I dont have the column named `created_at` and `updated_at` and also  i am not intrested with that column named. What I can do for this to save the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to turn off the auto timestamps from Laravel.

```
public timestamps = false;
```

put that in the model.